# US Visa Validity - B1/B2

Tags: usa

I have a B1/B2 US visa expiring in April 2019 and have a business trip planned in Feb 2019 for a week. I guess I should be alright, pls let me know if i am missing something I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4):

A US visa expiration date is the last date you are allowed to **enter** the US. It does not dictate when you have to leave the US. You can enter the US on the last date of validity if you like.